# Calling Method (with any parameter) from parameter

Tags: c#, opentk

I am trying to write a game with OpenTK.
I want to check the error everytime I call something from GL class.

so, let say, I have this class:

```
public static class GLCheck
{
    public static void Call(function f)
    {
        // Call f function
        CheckError();
    }

    public static void CheckError()
    {
        ErrorCode errorCode = GL.GetError();

        if (errorCode != ErrorCode.NoError)
            Console.WriteLine("Error!");
    }
}
```

so I can call function like this:

```
GLCheck.Call(GL.ClearColor(Color.White));
GLCheck.Call(GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview));
GLCheck.Call(GL.PushMatrix());
```

how can I do this?
thanks

----------------- **Answer:** -----------------

thanks for the answer!
I just realize all answers are using Delegate (*Action* or *Func<>*)
On .NET 2.0, this is not available, so you must create your own, here my GLCheck Class:

```
public static class GLCheck
{
    public delegate void Action();
    public delegate void Action<T1, T2>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2);
    public delegate void Action<T1, T2, T3>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3);
    public delegate void Action<T1, T2, T3, T4>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4);
    public delegate TResult Func<TResult>();
    public delegate TResult Func<T, TResult>(T arg);
    public delegate TResult Func<T1, T2, TResult>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2);
    public delegate TResult Func<T1, T2, T3, TResult>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3);
    public delegate TResult Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, TResult>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4);

    public static void Call(Action callback)
    {
        callback();
        CheckError();
    }

    public static void Call<T>(Action<T> func, T parameter)
    {
        func(parameter);
        CheckError();
    }
}
```

Once again, thanks for the answer!

Comment: That sounds like a horrible idea. Read about Exceptions

Comment: If OpenTK revolves around error codes, there's not much he can do about that. He can of course throw an exception in CheckError.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen That's right. I didn't consider that. *Sheepish*

Comment: Calling GL method wont throw any exception. if there are an error, GL.GetError() will not return NoError. In other words, I need to call CheckError() every time I call GL method. I just try to make it short, because there are a lot of GL method that I call in my games.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't be quite as tidy, but you can do this pretty easily with Lambda functions:

```
GLCheck.Call(() => GL.ClearColor(Color.White));
GLCheck.Call(() => GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview));
GLCheck.Call(() => GL.PushMatrix());
```

And `Call` would be defined like this:

```
public static void Call(Action a)
{
    a();
    CheckError();
}
```

In the case of methods GL methods without parameters, you can pass them in a bit more cleanly:

```
GLCheck.Call(GL.PushMatrix);
```

(note that there are no `()` after `PushMatrix`.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use generics to create something like this:

```
private void Call<T> (Action<T> func, T parameter)
{
    func(parameter);
    CheckError();
}
```

where T would be a parameter. Or you can use exceptions as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should just write your own API on top of the GL, thus resulting in much cleaner code. ie

```
public class MyGL
{
    private TypeHere GL = new TypeHere();

    public void ClearColor(Color color)
    {
        GL.ClearColor(color);
        CheckError();
    }

    private void CheckError()
    {
        ErrorCode errorCode = GL.GetError();

        if (errorCode != ErrorCode.NoError)
            Console.WriteLine("Error!");
    }
}
```

And thus you can call it with much more clear and readable code

```
MyGL.ClearColor(Color.White);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but.. wow... this crazy, there are lot of method that I call..

Comment: There are pros and cons in every way you can do things. You just have to consider which are your priorities, fast way to do things or more control.